# How to trigger controller and open new page (along with model) with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a link. Its triggers my ajax. I want to open a new page after this triger.
But it's returning back to my ajax after the trigger. There is my code.

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="SiparisYazdir(@item.id)" >Print</a>
```

**ajax**

```
function SiparisYazdir(id)
    {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Order/Print',
          type: 'GET',
          data: { "value": value, 'id': id } // value is taking from another method.
      });        
    }
```

**controller**

```
public IActionResult Print(int value, int id)
        {
            //taking model here
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

return View(model) will return the html content of your view
you cant put this  html into your desired tag

```
function SiparisYazdir(id)
    {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Order/Print',
          type: 'GET',
          data: { "value": value, 'id': id } // value is taking from another method.,
          success:(result)=>{
             $('your_desire_elemnt').html(result)
          }
      });        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another page, I think there is no need ajax here

```
function SiparisYazdir(id) {
    window.location.href = "/Home/Privacy?value=" + value + "&id=" + id;
}
```

Comment: i cant try this right now. Im not on computer. So can i trigger my controller with this ?